# Run a coded UI test using test agent

Tags: c#, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, automated-tests

I have created some Coded UI test using Page Object Model(no recordings ) and i have installed Test Agent as well as Test Controller. Test Agent Seems to show only the status, agent name,controller name and currently running test. I was told that test agent can be used to run tests, can anyone provide a link or some steps to run the tests

Thanks in advance

Arjun Menon

Comment: Please add some more relating tags: program language etc

Comment: How are you running the tests? Visual Studio? MTM?

Comment: Hi, during my search, i found that test agent can be used. But how , that i am still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Agent executes the test as directed by the controller.  The controller is sent tests to execute based on your settings in the TestSettings file.  Good information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182638.aspx).  In essence, though, you would select the settings file that has your desired test environment specified, and then click "run".  You cannot debug in a remote environment.

If you simply want to execute the tests on the machine the agent is installed, execute from command line via mstest.exe.  More info regarding this process [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I am trying to execute in a local machine that doesnot have VS installed. It seems i need to install Test Agent & execute using MsTest in command line.